# Edit ParentViewModel elements from Children.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have 3 usercontrols: parent and two children. Children inherit DataContext from parent and inside them i have a label (binding with the property labelstring of the parent viewmodel) and a button. I want that when i click on the button the parent viewmodel property change into the string "Clicked" how could i do that?
Thanks

Comment: Show some code in order for us to understand better what you are doing....

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please post some relevant code snippets as well as what you have attempted so far in order to receive reliable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the string from the code behind then you would be doing it this way.

Define an event handler for the click event of the button.
and inside that you will have

```
ParentViewModel vm = this.DataContext as ParentViewModel;
if(vm!=null)
{
vm.SomeTextProperty = "Clicked";
}
```

But I would suggest you to create an ICommand and bind that to Command property of the button and then you can play with the properties in the ViewModel itself without touching the code behind